# Tags Input With Autocomplete from array in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, autocomplete

I download this script https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Tags-Input-Autocomplete.html and i create route

```
Route::get('/ingredients-data', function(){
$data = Menu_Ingredient::all()->pluck('name')->toArray();
return response($data);
});
```

i wanna use this to source in autocomplete.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {              
            $('#form-tags-4').tagsInput({
                'autocomplete': {
                    source: [
                        'apple',
                        'banana',
                        'orange',
                        'pizza'
                    ]
                } 
            });

        });
    </script>
```

how i can do it to link route in source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should pass your data as encoded json to source :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {              
            $('#form-tags-4').tagsInput({
                'autocomplete': {
                    source: @json($data)
                } 
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also like to use the select2 in jquery. Ive used this select2, it has good documentation. You can check their documentation here [Select2](https://select2.org/)